# Replacing a value with anothe rone

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

Let's say I have 6 values

```
elem=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

f is always !=0 but one of the others is always = 0 (one at a time).

I'd like to know how to check which of the elem[] is equal to zero and replace this value with f in a newelem.

Ex.

```
elem=[1,2,3,0,5,6] --> newelem=[1,2,3,6,5]
```

now, I have something like this:

```
if elem[0]=0:
   newelem=[elem[6],elem[1],elem[2],elem[3],elem[4]]

elif elem[1]=0:
   newelem=[elem[0],elem[6],elem[2],elem[3],elem[4]]
```

etc...

Comment: Please format you post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x if x!=0 else elem[-1], elem))[:-1]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5]
```

Or with `list comprehension`:

```
[i if i!=0 else elem[-1] for i in elem][:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#a.index(0) Gets you the index of element with value 0
#a.pop() removes and returns the last element of the array

a[a.index(0)] = a.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop()`, just find which element you want to remove

```
>>> elem=[1,2,3,0,5,6]
>>> elem.pop(3)
0
>>> elem
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

end then push new element to this place

```
elem.insert( 3, 6)
```

after that simply once again pop elemem which was moved to place where you have "0"

Comment: 2 issues I see with this answer  . 1 ) The question is about replacing the 0 not adding one more element . 2 ) The index of 0 is not always 3

Comment: in this example it is on index 3. and I wrote that there is a need to find which index we want to remove. using at first pop, then insert we can replace element. of course we can recreate list without element we want to remove.